# python scapy filter pcap file

Tags: python, scapy, pcap

I have to filter packets from a pcap files and process them further.
The files are very large, therefore it's not feasible to read the entire thing into memory at once. Scapy seems to be very sophisticated and I was able to iterate through packets with

```
with PcapReader(pcap) as pcap_reader:
    for pkt in pcap_reader:
        ...
```

Unfortunately I was not able to find a way to apply a filter (e.g. BPF) to neither the `PcapReader` so only matching packets will be iterated nor the `pkt` (which should be `scapy.packet`!?).

I saw that there is a function `tdecode`, which is a tshark decoder which takes a filter as arguments, but there is no way of saving the resulting packets into a variable but just to flood the terminal with all results.

Is there a way of filtering packets from a .pcap file with `scapy` and still iterating over the results?

Comment: Can't you first filter with tshark (which is pretty fast) and then process the new pcap further with scapy? If your post processing is expensive you're probably better off using libpcap directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scapy is unbelievably slow, to the point where interactive use is the only use. It also does not allow filtering packets before full (in-python) dissection, which exasperates the problem.

You can use `libpcap`, either by writing a small C-extension yourself or by using a [binding](https://github.com/karpierz/libpcap), as a replacement for `PcapReader`. `libpcap` allows you to specify a filter in [BPF-syntax](https://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html), which is applied on the incoming packets within the library or - when capturing live from a device - by the kernel itself. This will vastly improve your performance.

The basic layout would be to:

- `open_offline()` a pcap-file
- set the BPF-filter
- read from the libpcap-supplied handle
- pass the incoming packet data to scapy for further inspection

You can get [quite sophisticated](https://github.com/JPaulMora/Pyrit/blob/master/cpyrit/pckttools.py#L486) with that.

Comment: Note nowadays you could simply `sniff(offline="a.pcap", prn=handler, filter="tcp", store=0)`. `filter` will accept any bpf filter

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tcpdump()` function to have a BPF filter applied.

```
with PcapReader(tcpdump("myfile.cap", args=["-w", "-", "my BPF filter"],
                        getfd=True)) as pcap_reader:
    for pkt in pcap_reader:
        print pkt.summary()
```

If that's of some interest for you, maybe you could submit a feature request, so that `PcapReader()` accepts a `filter` parameter (and behaves more or less like `sniff()` with an `offline=` parameter.

Comment: this is awesome! Just what I was looking for. This works great in Linux, but in OSX, i get no output. Checking the [docs](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.utils.html#scapy.utils.tcpdump), I see this, but am not fully sure how to implement this. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, this works great with the Brew version of tcpdump, but I am trying to make it work with the Apple version as well.